# Ember and Nested-Route-Madness with Bootstraps Active - Attribute

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, ember-router

I'm trying to get an App to work with Ember.js. The structure should be like:

[image]

I defined the routes like this:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.route("index", { path: "/" });
    this.route("about");
    this.resource('customer', { path: "/customer/:customer_id" }, function () {
        this.resource('customerCars', { path: '' }, function () {
            this.resource('customerCar', { path: '/Car/:car_id' }, function () {
                this.route('vehicledetails');
                this.route('engine');
            });
            this.route('create');

        });
    });
});
```

It works now till that point, that I can click at the "Audi" Link, and it transitions to "Vehicledetails". I am working with Bootstrap and I want the "Audi" link class to get the active - attribute. This is only possible if the Audi-Link inside my customerCars.index - Template is build like this:

```
  {{#each model}}
  {{#link-to  'customerCar.vehicledetails' id tagName='li' }}
  {{#link-to 'customerCar.vehicledetails' id}}
  {{viewName}}
  {{/link-to}}
  {{/link-to}}
  {{/each}}

  {{outlet}}
```

When the user then selects the "Engine" link, the "Audi"-Link loses its active attribute. I tried different route-definitions and link-to - versions. When I try to point the link-to at 'customerCar', then all links (Audi,Mercedes,Bike) get the active attribute when I select one of them.

Can anyone help me out of my confusion?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

The Problem here was, that I was using a broken Canary-Build of Ember (because I am using the Beta-Fature "Query-Params"). That specific Build handled the active link in a different way (I guess).

It works with the latest Canary-Build.